# The Mark of the Beast

Tags: revelation, history

I have been wondering if the Mark of the Beast has already happened. From Revelation:

> “He causes all, both small and great, rich and poor, free and slave,
>   to receive a mark on their right hand or on their foreheads, and that
>   no one may buy or sell except one who has the mark or the name of the
>   beast, or the number of his name.” Revelation 13:16-17

As I read through the history of the Inquisition it states that he caused those who converted to Catholicism or Christianity to receive a mark in their right hand and on their forehead.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: “As I read through the history of the Inquisition it states that he caused those Catholicism or Christianity to receive a mark in their right hand and on their forehead.”—Perhaps that is better asked on Skeptics Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2):

A simple outline for the book of Revelation is found in Revelation 1:19. In the first chapter, the risen and exalted Christ is speaking to John. Christ tells John to “write, therefore, what you have seen, what is now and what will take place later.” The things John had already seen are recorded in chapter 1. The “things which are” (that were present in John's day) are recorded in chapters 2–3 (the letters to the churches). The “things that will take place” (future things) are recorded in chapters 4–22. Generally speaking, chapters 4–18 of Revelation deal with God's judgments on the people of the earth.

While the Apostle John was still alive, it was common to brand slaves or enemy soldiers, or  to place the sign of the cross on the forehead of a new Christian.  During the time of the Roman Empire, "the mark of the beast" apparently symbolised allegiance to the demands of the imperial cult.

Looking ahead to the end-times and to the revealing of the Antichrist, the "mark of the beast" identifies those who submit to the Antichrist, who deny Christ. Last time I looked, Catholics and Protestants alike do not deny Christ.

God's judgments on the people of the earth and the identification of the Antichrist point to the future, not the past.

Source: New International Version Study Bible notes on Revelation 13:16