# Thoughts on the mark of the beast in Revelation 13:18, ESV. Already took place?

Tags: revelation

There are lots of people who believe that the mark of the beast is always a future thing we will endure.  However, those in the Amillennialist and Preterist view tend to believe this took place during the time of the writing of Revelation.

Domitian was a ruthless emperor in power at the time of this writing who demanded worship of himself and I heard that the term "mark of the beast" is metaphorical for worshipping someone or something other than Jesus.  I also heard that people in that time period had to say "Caesar is Lord," which would pose obvious problems for a faithful Christian.

I also read that these Christians in that day would have been prevented from "buying and selling."  Thus, the "mark" has already happened.  Any thoughts on this?  For me, this interpretation helps to take away from a lot of the fanatical explanations of this passage when we rest that it already took place.  In no way am I trying to demean other points of view on this passage.  I genuinely want to hear how others are making sense of the "mark of the beast."  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (Link below left) to better understand how this site works.  Valid questions here need a specific Bible passage to examine.

Comment: I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Mark of the Beast](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/35791/the-mark-of-the-beast)

Comment: Yes it already happened, it shouldn't be a surprise to know the books are written and meant to those to whom they were written, not for us.

Answer (score 2):

Revelation was written to be heard immediately as a spoken piece (Revelation 1:3).

I posit it must have made sense to 1st Century people on plain reading aloud.  So its terms and symbols (including 'the mark of the beast' whatever that might mean to us today) would have been recognised and understood by that audience.

There are 6 plain references to 'soon' or synonyms thereof in Revelation in a 1st Century context.

Comment: To clarify I'm not associating the number of references to soon with any meaning other than the plain mean of 'soon' as it would be understood by a 1st Century audience.

Answer (score 1):

The Beast could be both a past *and* a future person. Many commentators have shown that the number of the Beast [corresponds through gematria to Nero Caesar](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/%7Egrout/encyclopaedia_romana/gladiators/nero.html). However this does not rule out Domitian if John of Patmos wrote during his reign, because the author could have been signaling that Domitian was a latter-day version of Nero, who was likewise famous for persecuting Christians.

Almost every generation has seen its [candidates for Antichrist](https://blog.rose-publishing.com/2016/03/16/14-people-accused-of-being-the-anti-christ/), from [Frederick II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_II,_Holy_Roman_Emperor) to various popes, Martin Luther, Napoleon, Stalin, Hitler, JFK, Kissinger, Reagan, Gorbachev, [George Soros](https://antisemitism.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Final-George-Soros-Briefing.pdf), [Obama, Trump](https://apnews.com/article/europe-business-religion-michael-pence-832adb60afb243738eeaf66b7d6d77a8) and [Bill Gates](https://www.truthnetwork.com/show/the-christian-worldview-david-wheaton/17470/). It seems that concern about the Antichrist, like hope, springs eternal.

Answer (score 0):

**The Beast and its Mark** In interpreting this passage keep in mind that in the Bible "a Beast" always represents an Empire, or nation, not a Person! And here in Revelation, instead of focusing on a mean dude, as if one is intended, note that the Greek could/should be translated simply "man". (meaning, mankind)

And to point to the context of Revelation, which is the Roman occupation of Israel, it would be beneficial to note that since "number" are mentioned, the six Roman numerals add up to, you guessed it, 666!

I = 6 
V = 5
X = 10
L = 50
C = 100
D = 500
Total 666

The endless quest all throughout history by prophecy buffs to find a single man is like a quest for Shangri La. It is feckless. They do not fit the context of this text, nor the time-text. (Notice that the word, "antichrist" does not appear in this passage of REVELATION 13.)

As well, the antichrist has been tied to "the End Times" in most schemes. So, since there has been failure *to pin the tail in the donkey*, it also shows that their prognostications about it being the "End Times" has failed miserably. (They ignore Jesus declaration that there are NO signs of the End. Matthew 24:42,44)

And yet in every generation there are opportunists who exploit the congregations of God with the sale of books, videos, and seminars about the alleged antichrist.

Answer (score -1):

In our day and age, nations are ruled by its citizens through democracy, but before democracy, nations were ruled by hereditary autocratic rulers. That is; ruled by one person's whims and fancies. The main character trait of an autocratic ruler can be said to be the same as that of a wild animal - a beast, which would be: ruthlessness.

The spread of democracy has resulted in the disappearance of many beast kingdoms today. There are however a few smaller ones around in places such as Africa. China can hardly be called a beast nation, since western democracy voting does take place, although only between the factions of the party (DPC). The cultural revolution under Mao probably could be seen as having been a beast kingdom though.

Revelation speaks about seven big beasts. The first six beasts are big empires, transnational in nature. Rev 17:11 mentions an eighth beast, who seems to not be the seventh beast himself (Rev 20:10), but a person that is promoting the restoration of the seventh beast; the beast “that was, is not, but will come”. This was prophesied at the height of the power of the Roman empire so Rome has to be the sixth beast, and not the last seventh.

> “This calls for a mind with wisdom. The seven heads are seven hills on which the woman sits. They are also seven kings. Five have fallen, one is, the other has not yet come; but when he does come, he must remain for only a little while. The beast who once was, and now is not, is an eighth king. He belongs to the seven and is going to his destruction. (Rev 17:9-11)

Thus, the seventh and last beast has to be one of the other empires that comes back. Rev 13:2,3, which parallels Daniel 7, describes him as a beast with a Greek body (leopard) with adopted features from the Medo-Persian (bear) and Babylonian (lion) empires. So, it might mean a comeback of one of these three empires. There are evidences supporting the Greek empire making a comeback,  but it is not clear-cut.

Greece has the largest shipping industry in the world* so it would also be the country with most to lose when Mystery Babylon goes kaput. Thus, the nature and/or location of end time Babylon is a mystery, but it seems to be promoting the shipping industry in some crucial way.

> In one hour such great wealth has been brought to ruin!’
> “Every sea captain, and all who travel by ship, the sailors, and all who earn their living from the sea, will stand far off. When they see the smoke of her burning, they will exclaim, ‘Was there ever a city like this great city?’ They will throw dust on their heads, and with weeping and mourning cry out:
> “‘Woe! Woe to you, great city,
>     where all who had ships on the sea became rich through her wealth! In one hour she has been brought to ruin!’. (Rev 18:17-19)

- “Greek companies control 21% (2022) of the world's total merchant fleet, making it the largest in the world. They are ranked in the top 5 for all kinds of ships, including first for tankers and bulk carriers.“ (Greek shipping:Wikipedia)